# Checking if a list item combination already exists, and returning an alert using PreSaveAction function

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, custom-list, presaveaction

I'm creating a script that will override submit form functionality when the save button is clicked. The goal is to validate user input by checking if a combination of columns already exists within a list. If the combination exists it will alert the user that their input is not unique and to enter in new input. The first column, "Name", is of type single line of text. The second column, "Training", is a choice column.

Ex: If the list already has the name "Bob" and "T1" then this combination cannot be duplicated. If the user attempts to input the same values, "Bob" and "T1" , when they click the save button it should throw an alert. "Bob" and "T2" is unique would allow the user to submit that form.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
});
//PreSaveAction code to validate
function PreSaveAction()
{
  //Name variable
  var name = $('input[title="Name"]').val();
  //Training Variable
  var training = $('input[title="Training"]').val();
  
  //I'm trying to find a way to iterate through my list and compare the values that the user 
  //has just input to the existing list items and if there is a match then 
  //give an alert and return false 
  //also I'm assuming that an array might be beneficial to hold the variables?
  
  if(this.name & this.training !=null)
  {
  alert('Name and training already exist. Please Input Unique Values');
  return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated , really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a tricky problem, having to interrupt `PreSaveAction` to do some sort of async validation before you really know what you want to return from `PreSaveAction`.

How I have handled it in the past is to basically

- have a flag set to `false` to indicate whether I made my check
- when `PreSaveAction` fires, check the flag, if it's set one way, start the validation, but return `false` from `PreSaveAction` to prevent the item from saving
- do the validation
- set the flag to indicate the validation is done
- re-trigger `PreSaveAction` by simulating another click on Save from code

Some example code so you get the idea:

```
// declare some variables outside the scope of any function
// so you can access them from anywhere
var madeValidationCheck = false;
var duplicateFound = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    // whatever you have in here
});

function PreSaveAction() {
    // once PreSaveAction fires, see if you have done your validation
    if (!madeValidationCheck) {
        // the validation check hasn't happened yet, so we need to start that off.
        // since it is async and might take some time, i like to show the user that something is happening
        // so they don't get antsy
        $('input[id$="SaveItem"]').before('<img class="waitImage" src="' + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + '/_layouts/15/1033/images/progress16.gif" />');
        // now we start our function that has the async code in it
        DoAsyncValidation();
        // now, since we are waiting for the async validation
        // to finish, we _don't_ want the form to save yet so:
        return false;
    } else {
        // our madeValidationCheck is true, so we must have our validation
        // result by now, so clear the visual cue for waiting,
        // and return the _actual_ result we want from the validation,
        // which could eb either true or false
        $('img.waitImage').detach();

        // you could optionally show your alert here
        if (duplicateFound) {
            alert('duplicate found!')
        }

        return !duplicateFound;
    }
}

function DoAsyncValidation() {
    // get the values that you want to check
    var name = $('input[title="Name"]').val();
    var training = $('input[title="Training"]').val();

    // you don't need to iterate over anything. you can find out if
    // any items in your list have this value combination by using
    // a REST query and filtering for items that have both of these values
    var itemRequest = "https://your-server/sites/your-site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Your List')/items?$filter=Name eq '" + name + "' and Training eq '" + training +"'";
    $.ajax({
        url: itemRequest,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json;odatat=verbose'
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        // if you get _any_ results, you found a match
        // for that value pair, so all you care is if
        // you got more than zero results
        if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
            duplicateFound = true;
            // or you could optionally alert your error message here
            alert('duplicate found!')
        } else {
            duplicateFound = false;
        }

        // ok, now we have our validation results so
        // set the flag that you check in PreSaveAction
        madeValidationCheck = true;

        // and then trigger PreSaveAction again by "clicking" the save button
        $('input[id$="SaveItem"]').click();

    }).fail(function(jqXhr, status, error) {

        // not sure what you want to do if the REST request failed.
        // you could force the form not to save by pretending that the validation failed

        duplicateFound = true;
        madeValidationCheck = true;
        alert('sorry there was an error')
        $('input[id$="SaveItem"]').click();

        // OR
        //
        // you could have another flag variable for this case
        // which you could set here and check back in PreSaveAction
        // to know not to show the "duplicate found" message
        // but instead show a different error
        // but still return false from PreSaveAction again
        // to make sure the item is not saved

        // many ways to handle this, i can't really tell you what to do here
    });
}
```

Comment: This really helps a lot. So if I understand correctly, in the DoAsyncValidation function if the data results are less than 1, it would return false and change the PreSaveAction flag to true. This would allow the user to save because that is a unique combination.

Comment: If the data results are _anything greater than zero_, `duplicateFound` is set to `true`, then when the PreSaveAction runs for the second time it will return `!duplicateFound` i.e. "not" `duplicateFound` i.e. "not" `true` i.e. `false`, which is what you would want PreSaveAction to return to prevent saving. If the results are zero, `duplicateFound` is set to `false` (because no duplicates were found), so the second PreSaveAction returns `!duplicateFound` i.e. "not" `false` i.e. `true`, which is what you want PreSaveAction to return when no duplicates are found and it's OK to save.

Comment: After implementation , its giving duplicate found alerts even with combinations that don't exist in the list are entered. Is there any way around this ?

Comment: I believe its caused by the API request failing because it will always give the 'Sorry there was an error' alert.

Comment: Then you need to figure out how to get the API call to work.  My first guess is that the internal names of the columns you are checking against are not actually "Name" and "Training" because I don't know how you have your list set up. When you set up the API call to `$filter` for items, you need to use the _internal_ column names.  And again, I wrote extensively in the comments that I can't really tell you what to do if you get an API call error.  If you don't want it to trigger a "duplicate found" alert then figure out how to do that.

Comment: My point though is that ultimately if there is an API error, you probably want to _prevent_ the saving of the item because you haven't been able to actually check for the conditions that you are checking for.

Comment: Right, I understand the reasoning behind preventing saving now. Yeah looking at the query the internal column name for 'Name' is actually Title and Training is just that. Would I have to tinker with the API call syntax considering that Training is also a choice column?

Comment: *and or a change to the variable creation (var training = ...)

Comment: If it is a single-select choice field then no, you should be fine as it is: `FieldName eq 'desiredValue'` (notice the single quotes around the value you're looking for).  If it's a multi-select choice field, I'm not sure, you might have to tinker with it, you might not.  A bunch of conflicting answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5379371/988264).

Comment: API call seems to be working now however , just keep getting never ending save item loop image, gonna keep tinkering

Comment: Got it working after some jquery and api errors! Would there be a way to always make a validation check and just have DoasyncValidation run. Currently it works after they enter in non unique values but if they change inputs to a unique value it already assumes validation check has been done

Comment: If you add some event handlers to the inputs you can use those to reset the `madeValidationCheck` flag to `false` when the inputs change, and thus re-do the validation for the new combination.

Comment: I don't have ability to implement event recevers, could there be any other way within the logic? I tried just having the doasync function but it never actually saves

Comment: Not event receivers, event _handlers_ on the _inputs_.  You want to detect when the input changes (and "handle" that change event), so you know when to reset the flag variable. You're using jQuery, so if your inputs are dropdowns, `$(dropdown).change()`, or if they're textboxes then maybe `$(textbox).keyup()` is more appropriate.

Comment: Got it functioning! Thanks for the assistance and tips with this, issue. I genuinely appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Great! Consider accepting this as the answer and upvoting. :)

Comment: Will do! and @Dylan , one more question if I may ask, I'm trying to add a custom error message under the training field in the from, telling the user that their choice is not unique. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Well, you're using jQuery, which is great for stuff like that. I'd use jQuery to find the spot in the form where you want to add the error message, and then use it to insert a `span` or `div` or something there with the error message you want to show.

Comment: so i found it as <span class="ms-metadata">Trainings</span> how would i append my own message there?

Comment: Just google around for "how to add an element to a page with jQuery", there's tons of examples out there.

Comment: Got it! learned a lot working through  this , gonna keep learning!